# How to stream mysql events to redis using debezium?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, redis, debezium

We are trying to use mysql as source db and redis as sink to build an ETL

I have specified the sink as redis using following properties

```
debezium.sink.type=redis
debezium.sink.redis.batch.size=500
debezium.sink.redis.address=redis:6379
debezium.sink.redis.message.format=compact
```

But starting the debezium is throwing the error that below two keys do not have valid values. These keys are for kafka, so how to modify this to redis?

```
schema.history.internal.kafka.topic
schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers
```

**Exact error:** "The 'schema.history.internal.kafka.topic' value is invalid: A value is required"

**Ref:** https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-example-configuration

Is this even possible to have Redis as sink with mysql connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct configuration which worked

debezium.source.schema.history.internal=io.debezium.relational.history.MemorySchemaHistory

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the values that are required and don't have default value as per [debezium docs](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-property-include-schema-changes), you must include the topic where it will track the DDL updates, and the kafka cluster that it will point to should be the same that the kafka-connect is using, below is the statement from the docs regarding `schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers`

> A list of host/port pairs that the connector uses for establishing an initial connection to the Kafka cluster. This connection is used for retrieving the database schema history previously stored by the connector, and for writing each DDL statement read from the source database. Each pair should point to the same Kafka cluster used by the Kafka Connect process.

Regarding the redis part, I didn't try it myself, but as per the docs, yes it is doable, check this [link (Debezium Redis Stream)](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/operations/debezium-server.html#_redis_stream)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you saying though we have the redis as sink, we need to have kafka as service to store the database schema history?

Comment: Is this something new with mysql connector? Because we are able to use the debezium with only redis as sink using postgresql connector

Comment: you can suppress the schema updates tracking by setting this flag to false `include.schema.changes`, even if you set it to false, you can’t skip setting the 2 above fields as as mentioned before they are required fields and don’t have default values

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I was busy trying in making this setup work. Point is we have done the integration with only debezium and redis for postgres. But for MySQL integration, Kafka is mandatory for storing schema changes as you mentioned. And I am trying to use redis as sink and use kafka only for schema changes. But no luck achieving this, do you think its possible whatever I am trying with mysql

Comment: what do you mean by using redis as sink and kafka for only schema changes, can you elaborate more?

Comment: Actually I have done the entire working prototype with debezium, redis(sink), postgres(source) without kafka at all. But when I am doing the same thing with mysql as source, it is expecting these keys as mandatory `schema.history.internal.kafka.topic`,`schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers`. So trying to figure out a way with having only redis as sink

Answer (score 0):

Debezium Server can optionally store 3 types of data in the sink:

1. change records
2. schema history (needed for MySql and Oracle)
3. Offset

In order to store schema history in Redis, add the following configuration:

```
debezium.source.schema.history.internal=io.debezium.storage.redis.history.RedisSchemaHistory
```

In order to store offsets in Redis, add the following configuration:

```
debezium.source.offset.storage=io.debezium.storage.redis.offset.RedisOffsetBackingStore
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After making changes, it is saying `Unable to find class io.debezium.storage.redis.history.RedisSchemaHistory`, and connector is getting stopped

Comment: Can you please help with this issue?